# Find element in array using mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongojs

I simply want to count the element in array based on the query. I tried the following command but not solved my problem.

I want to count the element whose TimeStamp is in between "2017-02-17T18:30:00.000Z and "2017-02-18T18:29:59.999Z" on DATA2 array, but it returns only 1.

CODE Executed:

CODE 1

```
db.ABC.aggregate([{
                $match: {
                    $and: [{

                        DATA2: {
                            $exists: true
                        }

                    }, {
                        "DATA2.TimeStamp": {
                            $gte: require('../../modules/getDates').getFromDate(item),
                            $lte: require('../../modules/getDates').getToDate(item)
                        }
                    }, {
                        Client_id: "123" /*req.query.client_id*/
                    }]
                }
            }, {


                $project: {

                    DATASiz: {
                        $size: "$DATA2"
                    },
                    "has bananas": {
                        $in: ["DATA2.$.TimeStamp"]
                    }
                }
            }], function(err, result) {

                console.log(result)
                callBack();

            })
```

Code 2

```
db.abc.find({ $and:[{DATA2: {$exists: true}},{Client_id: "123"},{"DATA2": { $elemMatch: { TimeStamp: {  $gte: require('../../modules/getDates').getFromDate(item), $lte: require('../../modules/getDates').getToDate(item) } } }}]
 }, function(err, result) {

             console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
             callBack();

           })
```

Code 3

```
//db.abc.find //also tried
    db.abc.count({
                    $and: [{

                        DATA2: {
                            $exists: true
                        }

                    }, {
                        "DATA2.TimeStamp": {
                            $gte: require('../../modules/getDates').getFromDate(item),
                            $lte: require('../../modules/getDates').getToDate(item)
                        }
                    }, {
                        Client_id: "123" /*req.query.client_id*/
                    }]
                },{
                    "DATA2.$":1
                }, function(err, result) {

                    console.log(result)
                    callBack();

                })
```

JSON Format:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "57c7404985737e2c78fde6b3"
    },
    "ABC": "1304258470",
    "Status": "Not Found",
    "DATA1": [
        {123},{123},{123}
    ],
    "Remark": "Not Found",
    "DATA2": [
        {
            "TimeStamp": "2017-02-18T09:01:43.060Z",
            "NdrStatus": "Door Locked",

        },
        {
            "TimeStamp": "2017-02-18T08:09:43.347Z",
            "NdrStatus": "HOLD",

        },
        {
            "TimeStamp": "2017-02-20T08:09:43.347Z",
            "NdrStatus": "HOLD",

        }
    ]
}
```

Result:
I am getting the first element of DATA2 using CODE 3 but I know that as per the query 2 elements are to return.

I expect 2 as in count. 
Also used $unwind $redact 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your MongoDB server version?

Comment: mongod version: 3.2.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** and **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size)** operators for this:

```
var start = require('../../modules/getDates').getFromDate(item),
    end   = require('../../modules/getDates').getToDate(item);

db.ABC.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "DATA2": { "$exists": true },
            "DATA2.TimeStamp": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end },
            "Client_id": "123"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "DATASiz": {
                "$size": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$DATA2",
                        "as": "item",
                        "cond": {
                            "$and": [
                                { "$gte": ["$$item.TimeStamp", start] },
                                { "$lte": ["$$item.TimeStamp", end] }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
], function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
    callBack();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my time. :) I forgot to try $filter :( Thank You Again.